# Attempting to include this var in the test.txt file using sed command to remove double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh, substitution

I'm attempting to include this **var** in the **test.txt** file using `sed` command.

Tried below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="test 'test:test:1.0'"
sudo sed -i '/dependencies {/a '"${var}"'' test.txt
```

test.txt

```
  dependencies {        
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'        
    }
}

group = 'org.gradle'
```

I'm using `sed` to do it, and it's updating the `test.txt` file, but it's adding with double quotes,

**Current script result:**

```
dependencies {
"test 'test:test:1.0'"
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'        
    }
}

group = 'org.gradle'
```

and if i remove the double quotes from the variable or `sed` command results in an error.

Error

```
sed: can't read 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.2'": No such file or directory
```

How can I ignore this double quotes?

Comment: Can't reproduce, [link to repl](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/GiddyFavorableDesktopenvironment#main.sh). Please post the output of `declare -p var` or `set -x` of execution of the script. Your variable _is not_ `var="test 'test:test:1.0'"` but it's `var="\"test 'test:test:1.0'\""`.

Comment: This smells a lot like an issue with a similar cause to [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- which is to say, misunderstanding of the difference between syntactic and literal quotes. (If you had only _syntactic_ double quotes -- as the code shown in the question does -- you wouldn't have this problem, as KamilCuk's linked reproducer demonstrates; thus, you must instead have literal ones).

Answer (score 0):

If I use OP's `var` assignment ...

```
var="test 'test:test:1.0'"
```

... then OP's `sed` generates:

```
  dependencies {
test 'test:test:1.0'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    }
}
```

In other words, I'm unable to reproduce the issue.

On the other hand if, as KamilCuk's surmised, `var` contains double quotes, eg:

```
var="\"test 'test:test:1.0'\""
```

... then I can duplicate OP's output.

So, assuming the double quotes are actually part of what's assigned to `var`, one idea is to use paramater substitution, eg:

```
var="\"test 'test:test:1.0'\""
sed "/dependencies {/a ${var//\"/}" test.txt
```

**NOTE:** once OP is satisfied with the results the `-i` flag can be added back into the `sed` call

This generates:

```
  dependencies {
test 'test:test:1.0'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
var="test 'test:test:1.0'"
sed '/dependencies {/{n;h;G;s/\S.*\n/'"$var"'\n/}' file
```

I too cannot reproduce the OP's problem.

However this solution does indent the inserted line at the same depth and in the correct place.